# Concorrência em java, exemplo simples, hash map nao seguro a múltiplas threads

Tags: java, concorrência

Estou utilizando um hash map para atribuir o `voto` ao `id` de um eleitor.
Porém a classe tem diversos threads operando em cima do método `addVote(...)` e `getVoteCount(...)` , e o resultado retornado é sempre inconsciente, apesar deu ter usado a versão `synchronized` de hash map, Alguém sabe explicar porque ainda não esta thread safe? Alguma sugestão de como eu posso arrumar

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SimpleVoteCounter {
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> electionsResults = 
            Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    protected void addVote(Integer id){
        Integer old = electionsResults.get(id);
        int value = (old == null) ? 1 : old + 1;
        electionsResults.put(id, value);
    }

    protected Integer getVoteCount(Integer id){
        return electionsResults.get(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa sincronizar o `HashMap` nem adotar `ConcurrentHashMap`. Basta sincronizar os métodos que o acessam:

```
public class SimpleVoteCounter {
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> electionsResults = new HashMap<>();
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    protected void addVote(Integer id){
        synchronized(lock) {
            Integer old = electionsResults.get(id);
            int value = (old == null) ? 1 : old + 1;
            electionsResults.put(id, value);
        }
    }

    protected Integer getVoteCount(Integer id){
        synchronized(lock) {
            return electionsResults.get(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Adotei um objeto `lock` à parte por questão de preferência, você pode sincronizar o método em si (`protected synchronized void addVote()`) ou ainda sincronizar sobre o próprio `HashMap` (`synchronized(electionsResults) { ... }`) que dá no mesmo.

Comment: Mas vc sabe dizer o porque o ConcurrentHashMap do modo que implementei nao estava seguro? eu achei que essa era a função da library

Comment: ahhh entendi, muito obrigado!

Comment: Seria seguro se as operações sobre ele fossem atômicas, apesar dos múltiplos acessos simultâneos. Como `addVote()` não é atômico, é necessário "atomizar" a operação com o bloco `synchronized`. Quando você faz isso, a classe já acaba ficando segura para manipular o `HashMap` sem risco de concorrência.

Comment: eu tentei como voce sugeriu, mas agora eu recebo um aviso depois de rodar o código referente a um numero excessivo de sincronizações, que esta diminuindo a performance, porém os resultados estão corretos. Vou tentar também com o Concurrent HashMap, deve ter alguma função que faça esse trabalho, pra comparar a performance

Comment: Tem alguma coisa errada no seu código então. Poste ele para dar uma olhada. Isso de número excessivo de sincronizações eu nunca vi acontecer. Se for o caso faça uma nova pergunta.